# Enum dropdownlistfor issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I've read a possible solution to this, but would require a lot of rewriting, the possible solution is linked [here](http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23), but there wouldn't be any sense to doing it that way if I am just a couple words off in my dropdownlistfor.

I'm having an issue with my dropdownlistfor as this is all new to me:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pageID, new SelectList (Enum.GetNames(typeof(PageIndex)), EnumHelper.GetSelectedItemList<PageIndex>().SelectedValue))
```

Trying to grab the "description" of my enum values as the drop down lists text values, then have an integer value returned to the database on POST.

Here's my enum:

```
public enum PageIndex : int
{
    [Description("Developmental Disabilities Tip Sheet")]
    ddTipSheets = 1,

    [Description("Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")]
    Example1 = 2,

    [Description("I don't know what I'm doing")]
    Example2 = 3
};
```

and my EnumHelper:

```
public class EnumHelper
{
    public static SelectList GetSelectedItemList<T>() where T : struct
    {
        T t = default(T);
        if (!t.GetType().IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Please make sure that T is of Enum Type"); }

        var nameList = t.GetType().GetEnumNames();

        int counter = 0;

        Dictionary<int, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        if (nameList != null && nameList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var name in nameList)
            {
                T newEnum = (T) Enum.Parse(t.GetType(), name);
                string description = getDescriptionFromEnumValue(newEnum as Enum);

                if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(counter))
                {
                    myDictionary.Add(counter, description);
                }
                counter++;
            }

            counter = 0;

            return new SelectList(myDictionary, "Key", "Value");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static string getDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute =
            value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

        return descriptionAttribute == null ? 
            value.ToString() : descriptionAttribute.Description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use ASP.NET 5.1 ?

Comment: I took a different approach, thanks though for reviewing my question.